# Copy one pre tags content to another on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I am writing a flask webapp. Here is the content of one of my web apps page.

What I want is to copy the content of pre tag with id "editor2" to "editor1" on button click. I am using ace editor.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<pre id="editor1" style="width: 600px; height: 500px; display: inline-block;"></pre>

<button type="button" onclick="fork()" class="btn btn-primary" style="vertical-align: middle;">Fork</button>

<pre id="editor2" style="width: 600px; height: 500px; display: inline-block;"></pre>
<p id="id">hey</p>

<script>
var editor1 = ace.edit("editor1");
editor1.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

var editor2 = ace.edit("editor2");
editor2.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor2.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>

<script>
function fork(){
    var text = document.getElementById("editor2").value;
    document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Rightnow when I click button the "editor1" pre content get replaced by text "undefined" and it becomes inactive i.e. i am not able to write in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fork() {
    var text =  editor2.getSession().getValue();
    editor1.getSession().setValue( text );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works and solves both of my problem. But why "document.getElementById('editor1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('editor2').innerHTML;" from answer of @hon2a makes the editor1 uneditable.

Comment: Because the Ace editor does not directly use the editor objects for storage, it utilizes a virtual renderer. See http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor

Answer (score 0):

A generic `Element`, like your `<pre>`, doesn't have any `.value` (that's why you're getting `undefined`). You can get its contents using `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = document.getElementById('editor2').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks now it is not giving undefined. But editor1 becomes uneditable i.e. i can't edit it anymore after button click.

Comment: What I've given you is just an answer to "how do I copy on element's content to another element". As for "how do I use code from an element and edit it using some library", you have to consult your library's API. I've never seen/used `flask`.

Comment: I guess it is not related to flask. @Richard Denton solution works just fine.

PS: your solution is perfect for title of my question but I can't even upvote coz it requires 15 reputation :/

Comment: It most certainly is related to some library, because whatever @Richard Denton's code uses, it's certainly not native DOM API or core JavaScript :) You should probably add that particular technology to the title of your question or its tags.